# Force of interest

Tags: finance

Suppose the force of interest over the time interval $[1,3]$ is given by $\delta (t) =\alpha +\beta t^{-1}$. If $100$ invested at $t=1$ grows to $120.74$ at $t=2$ and $100$ invested at $t=2$accumulates to $114.00$ at $t=3$. Find $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

$A(2)=e^{\int^2_1 (\alpha+\frac{\beta}{t})dt=\frac{120.74}{100}}$

$A(3)=e^{\int^3_2 (\alpha+\frac{\beta}{t})dt=\frac{114}{100}}$

$\rightarrow \alpha+\ln {2^\beta}=\ln{\frac{120.74}{100}}$ and

$\alpha + \ln{\frac{3}{2}^\beta}=\ln{\frac{114}{100}}$

Eliminating $\alpha$

$\beta=\frac{\ln{\frac{114}{100}}}{\ln{\frac{4}{3}}}$

But this does not yield the answer.

Comment: Can you clean up the problem statement - something seems wrong as written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expressions
$$A(2)=e^{\int^2_1 (\alpha+\frac{\beta}{t})dt=\frac{120.74}{100}}$$
$$A(3)=e^{\int^3_2 (\alpha+\frac{\beta}{t})dt=\frac{114}{100}}$$
are  meaningless. 
I think you wanted to write
$$A(2)=e^{\int^2_1 (\alpha+\frac{\beta}{t})dt}=\frac{120.74}{100}$$
$$A(3)=e^{\int^3_2 (\alpha+\frac{\beta}{t})dt}=\frac{114}{100}$$
From this we get (by taking logarithms)

$$\int^2_1 (\alpha+\frac{\beta}{t})dt =\log{\frac{120.74}{100}}$$
$$\int^3_2 (\alpha+\frac{\beta}{t})dt=\log{\frac{114}{100}}$$
and further
$$\alpha+ \beta  \ln2 =\log{\frac{120.74}{100}} $$
$$\alpha+ \beta  \ln\frac{3}{2} =\log{\frac{114}{100}} $$
This results in
$$\beta=\frac{\log 120.74-\log{114}}{\log4-\log3}=\frac{\log\frac{120.74}{114}}{\log\frac{4}{3}}$$

Answer (score 2):

You did the main , stating A(2) and A(3) and computing the integrals ...

$A(2)={e^{\int^2_1 (\alpha+\frac{\beta}{t})dt}= e^{{\alpha} + {\beta} \cdot \ln(2)} = \frac{120.74}{100}}$

$A(3)={e^{\int^3_2 (\alpha+\frac{\beta}{t})dt}= e^{{\alpha} + {\beta} \cdot \ln(3/2)}=\frac{114}{100}}$

Then we have merely a *system of 2 linear equations with 2 unknowns* ${\alpha}$ and ${\beta}$ :

- ${\alpha}+ {\beta} \cdot \ln(2) = \ln(1.2074)$
- ${\alpha} + {\beta} \cdot \ln(\frac{3}{2}) = \ln(1.14)$

and the solutions are ${\alpha} \approx 0.0500697$ and ${\beta} \approx 0.199668$

I'm looking for the error, not understanding well what you did after *Eliminating $\alpha$* , but miracle173 had found them both in your calculus and the mine. Now it is fixed.

Comment: so $$\beta = \frac{1.2074-1.14}{\ln(2)-\ln(\frac{3}{2})}$$

Comment: @miracle173 : I don't understand what you mean. The purpose is not to detail how to solve the linear system, the OP knows the integrals ... My last sentence is just friendly politeness :)

Comment: I wanted to point at the fact that your $\beta$ and th OP's $\beta$ have a different numerator. But as far as I can see your $\beta$ is wrong, too. I posted the correct $\beta$  in an answer.

Comment: @miracle173 : I computed something similar to your expression using a determinant resolver and the decimal values are the same. What did you find different ? [wolfram to compute the expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=X+%3D+%7B1.2074-1.14%7D%2F%7Blog+2+-log+1.5+%7D) while the mine with a decimal less is *0.23429*

Comment: check the numerators of $\beta$. yours is $1.2074−1.14$ mine is $\log 1.2074− \log 1.14$

Comment: @miracle173 yes ! you are true ! it is fixed , TY !

Comment: I think you should also fix the wrong format of the equations. I assume this format led to your wrong solution.